# Limit of Reciprocal Irrational Power Functions at Infinity

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $c$ be a real number. Many books state that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{c}{x^r}=0$$

if $r$ is positive and **rational**.

This limit still holds if $r$ is positive and **real**, right? If so, then why do so many authors restrict $r$ to being a rational number?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{c}{x^r}=0$$
for all positive reals. Restricting $r$ to rationals might occur in a teaching setting where $x^r$ has been defined for rational $r$, but has not yet been defined for real $r$.

One *can* define $x^y$ for real $y$ once one knows the meaning of $x^r$ for rational $r$. However, the properties of the resulting function are not very pleasant to verify.

The smooth way to define $x^y$ is as $\exp(y\ln x)$. There are various ways to introduce the exponential function and the natural logarithm. Often it is done substantially later than rational powers. There are even calculus courses that delay the introduction of transcendental functions!

Comment: Posted a link to this answer [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141/the-crusade-of-answers)

Comment: @gebruiker: When a question is answered, it automatically ends up, for a little while, in the "active" list. There is I think in this case no need to draw additional attention.  (But "tidying up" is a good thing!)